# How to filter a column in LibreOffice with some specific characters

Tags: filter, libreoffice-calc

I have a LibreOffice-Calc file like this:

[image]

There is a column called "code" here. How can I filter those based on "code" column that are in the style of ""11*-1*-91*-700"". 
Character * here means any character.

I mean the output is the same as this:

```
1121-117-912-700
1122-121-912-700
1121-117-911-700
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a *Standard Filter* on the Code column. When you get to the Standard Filter dialog, click <kbd>Options</kbd> and check Regular expression.

Set the Field name to Code, the Condition to = and supply the following for Value,

```
^11.?.?-1.?.?-91.?-700
```

Each question mark (e.g. `?`) represents a single wildcard character and must be accompanied by a prefix period (aka `.` or *full stop*).

[image: OpenOffice Calc RegEx Filter]

I didn't type out all of your sample data but I did type out enough to verify an answer.

You will also have to make sure that Tools ► Options ► OpenOffice Calc ► Calculate has *Enable regular expressions in formulas* enabled.

Comment: Great. Thank you. What is the character '^'

Comment: ASCII character 094 (e.g. `^`, *caret* or capital-six) is a RegEx code that shows that the first 1 immediately following it is intended to be the first character in the string. Sort of a *starts with...* thing. Some people get away without using it; I've always used it so I continue to do so.